# Hyperledger Composer "FROM" query language

Tags: hyperledger-composer

The documentation for Query language (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/query-language.html) mentions the keyword `FROM`.

Is there an example on how/when to use `FROM`?

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM` keyword allows the query to reference resources stored in a custom registry. By default assets of a given type are stored in a registry named with the same name as the fully qualified type name. Using `FROM` allows the developer to override this default behaviour.

For example, an application developer could choose to store some car assets in a registry called `ImportedCars`, separate from other cars.